# Java: Repeated column in mapping for collection

Tags: java, spring, postgresql, jpa

I am trying to create a `OneToMany` mapping with a `LinkedHashMap` for my main entity `B`, that contains the entities `VC` and `P`, but I am getting the following error:

> Repeated column in mapping for collection:
> com.test.model.B.pricing column: b_name

I could be wrong, but I believe that it has something to do with the `@JoinColumns` or `@MapKeyJoinColumn` annotation, as I have not done anything like this before, so I am quite sure that I am doing this part incorrectly.

My goal is that I should be able to provide the three fields:

`b_name` `pc` and `c_id` e.g. the `VC/VCId`

in order to get the `a` and `d_a` e.g. `P`.

Also, if there is a better way to structure things, then I am all ears, as I personally do not really like how I have set up my tables tbh (would be nice if I could just have the `b` and `b_p` tables, where the `b_p` could just have all five fields (key and value) from the `p` map).

Here is my main entity

```
@Setter
@Getter
@Entity
@Table(name = "b")
public class B implements Serializable {

  @Id
  @Column(nullable = false)
  private String name;

  @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST)
  @JoinTable(
          name = "b_p",
          joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "b_name", referencedColumnName = "name"))
  @MapKeyJoinColumns({
          @MapKeyJoinColumn(name = "b_name"),
          @MapKeyJoinColumn(name = "p_c"),
          @MapKeyJoinColumn(name = "c_id")
  })
  private Map<VC, Price> pricing = new LinkedHashMap<>();

  ...
}
```

The Key to the map

```
@Setter
@Getter
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Entity
@Table(name = "v_c")
public class VC implements Serializable {

  @EmbeddedId private VCId vcId;
}
```

The key's PK/Composite Key

```
@Setter
@Getter
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Embeddable
public class VCId implements Serializable {

  @Column(name = "b_name")
  private String bName;

  @Column(name = "p_c")
  private SomeEnum pc;

  @Column(name = "c_id")
  private String cId;
}
```

The value for the map

```
@Setter
@Getter
@NoArgsConstructor
@Embeddable
@Entity
@Table(name = "price")
public class Price implements Serializable {

  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
  @Column(name = "id")
  private long id;

  @Column(name = "amount")
  private BigDecimal amount;

  @Column(name = "discount_amount")
  private BigDecimal discountAmount;
}
```

DB tables

```
CREATE TABLE b
(
    name                    VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY
    ...
);

CREATE TABLE v_c
(
    bundle_name         VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
    physical_currency   TEXT         NOT NULL,
    coin_id             VARCHAR(50)  NOT NULL,

    FOREIGN KEY (b_name) REFERENCES b (name) ON DELETE CASCADE,
    PRIMARY KEY (b_name, p_c, c_id)
);

CREATE TABLE p
(
    id                  BIGSERIAL    NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    amount              NUMERIC,
    discount_amount     NUMERIC      DEFAULT 0.00
);

CREATE TABLE b_p
(
    bname         VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
    p_c   TEXT    NOT NULL,
    c_id          VARCHAR(50)  NOT NULL,
    price_id      BIGSERIAL    NOT NULL,

    FOREIGN KEY (b_name, p_c, c_id) REFERENCES v_c (b_name, p_c, c_id) ON DELETE CASCADE,
    FOREIGN KEY (price_id) REFERENCES price (id) ON DELETE CASCADE,
    PRIMARY KEY (b_name, p_c, c_id)
);
```

Comment: It seems counterintuitive to have bundle_name be part of the VirtualCurrency. Don't you want your virtual currency to be available for multiple bundles ?

Comment: @Lookslikeitsnot well the only reason why I have the bundle_name a part of that is just because I want to to make sure that I get the right VirtualCurrency for a specific bundle. In theory, it is totally fine and 100% possible that another bundle can have the same VirtualCurrency, in fact it is expect, but the Pricing of each bundle in the end can be different. If I can achieve this without using the bundle_name as part of the composite key, then I 100% would.

Comment: Isn't that achieved by having the b_name in b_p and b_name, p_c, c_id being the PK of that table ? 
Add `FOREIGN KEY (b_name) REFERENCES b (name) ON DELETE CASCADE` to b_p and you could remove b_name from v_c.

Comment: @Lookslikeitsnot awesome, thanks a bunch, mate!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To prevent repeated mapping error, you just have to specify which join should update the column like such:

```java
@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST)
@JoinTable(name = "bundle_pricing",
  joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "bundle_name",
    referencedColumnName = "name"))
@MapKeyJoinColumns({
  @MapKeyJoinColumn(name = "bundle_name", insertable = false, updatable = false),
  @MapKeyJoinColumn(name = "physical_currency"), @MapKeyJoinColumn(name = "coin_id")})
private Map<VirtualCurrency, Price> pricing = new LinkedHashMap<>();
```

**NOTE** the `insertable = false, updatable = false` for bundle_name in the MapKeyJoinColumn

Answer (score 1):

remove the `@MapKeyJoinColumn(name = "bundle_name")` from MapKeyJoinColumns, because when we are creating the JoinColumn in JoinTable it will create the column we don't need to mention it again.

```
@JoinTable(
          name = "bundle_pricing",
          joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "bundle_name", referencedColumnName = "name"))
  @MapKeyJoinColumns({
          @MapKeyJoinColumn(name = "physical_currency"),
          @MapKeyJoinColumn(name = "coin_id")
  })
```

Comment: Thanks, that got rid of that error but now its giving this: A Foreign key refering com.test..base.model.VirtualCurrency from com.test.base.model.Bundle has the wrong number of column. should be 3